# Can I use directory environment variables in FileUtils.mkdir_p, Ruby, WIndows?

Tags: ruby, windows, directory, wildcard

I want to make a simple function that allows me to output error-logs to a file somewhere outside of my project directory. I don't want these random error logs to be included in the project files at the repository, so rather than risk 'forgetting' to delete them, I'd rather just write them somewhere else.

I want to make the code usable across different accounts by including the %username% wildcard in the directory path. However, the `FileUtils.dir_p` function creates the directorty `C:/Users/%username%/` rather than the intended

```
def log_to_file(params)     
    time = Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S')

    dir = "C:/Users/%username%/Documents/RailsDevLogs/#{time.to_s}.txt" 
    #this doesn't work

    #dir = "C:/Users/majinbuu/Documents/RailsDevLogs/#{time.to_s}.txt" 
    #this works

    begin
        FileUtils.mkdir_p('C:/Users/%username%/Documents/RailsDevLogs/') 
            unless File.exist?('C:/Users/%username%/Documents/RailsDevLogs/')

        logs = File.open(dir,'a+')
        logs.write(params)
        logs.close()

    rescue => e
        puts "dir error => #{e}"
    end
end
```

So my question is, can I use wildcards (**[EDIT] sorry, ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES**) in Ruby file strings, and if so, how do I used them?

Comment: `%...%` is not wild card, it represents environment variable

Comment: There are no wildcards in your code. Can you clarify your question, please? What is your *exact* problem? How *exactly* are you using wildcards? Please show the code *actually* using the wildcards.

Comment: Sorry for not being Pi, Pie, Pye-hot (whichever terminology is accepted within your computing master-race) on Windows OS directory reference/ command terminology/ jargon. What I meant was "environment variable" (thank you for pleasantly correcting me Wand Maker). There is no need to be passive aggressive, rude or patronising within your useless reply @Jörg W Mittag. I find stackoverflow to be one of the most helpful resources on the web. It is however, ruined by users who make it seem as if the inexperience/ enthusiastic learners are unwelcome.

Comment: @JayJay  Don't think Jorg was being rude, he used "please", twice. His answers are generally very elaborate and informative - he probably was making sure that he gives answer after understanding the issue fully. Relax, and it may not be a bad idea to delete the above comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code to get current user's home directory:

```
home_dir = ENV["HOME"]
```

Then you can do:

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p("#{home_dir}/app_name/logs")
```

Even better would be to allow user to specify log directory by providing config option in your code.   Simplest choice would be to have user define an environment variable, say MY_APP_LOG_DIR, and then do:

```
log_dir = ENV["MY_APP_LOG_DIR"
FileUtils.mkdir_p("#{log_dir}")
```

In Ruby, typical convention is to use `YAML` files for specifying configuration. You can read about them.

Comment: Cheers, that's all I wanted- apologies for the terminology confusion- that was probably the route of my problem!